# How to set up Hydrogen in Pulsar IDE

Tags: hydrogen, pulsar-editor

I am trying to set up Hydrogen on the Pulsar IDE and I can't get it to work.  It is really disappointing as ATOM + Hydrogen was brilliant (Hydrogen has over 2.5 million downloads), but set up on Pulsar is sooooooo difficult.

I am on Windows 10.

I am trying to follow this guide: https://pipegalera.com/posts/pulsar-hydrogen/

I have Pulsar installed on my machine as evidenced by the screenshot below:

[image]

But when I attempt step 2 which is to type:

```
pulsar -p install https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen -t v2.16.5
```

into the terminal, `pulsar` is not recognised.

In windows powershell I get:

[image]

And in the Anaconda command line I get:

[image]

Desperately need help!   How can I get Hydrogen working on Pulsar in Windows 10??

Answer (score 1):

Mine does not work either but at least the command is recognized; hydrogen does not just install after that. In your case trying adding pulsar to path or you environment variables

Comment: Thanks.  Will keep working on it and will post a solution if I get it going.